How do I await wgpu::device.poll()
Is there any way to await a the completion of a command buffer asynchronously in rust. to my knowledge, device.poll() is not async in the wgpu API, but it is async on the GPU.
I want to be able to write a line like this
device.poll(wgpu::Maintain::WaitForSubmissionIndex(idx)).await;

The word "async" means very different things when used in the context of controlling a GPU device v.s. the context of Rust. In the former case, it merely means that the commands you send return immediately without blocking your CPU thread; in the latter, it very specifically refers to an ecosystem of libraries that implement and work with std::future::Future. Do not conflate the two because they are fundamentally different concepts.
I think the ideal solution would be to create a Future wrapper around Device::poll, something like this:
/// This is probably not a great name but that's besides the point.
struct DeviceReady<'a> {
    device: &'a wgpu::Device,
    idx: wgpu::SubmissionIndex,
}
impl std::future::Future for DeviceReady {
    type Output = ();
    fn poll(self: std::pin::Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut std::task::Context<'_>) -> std::task::Poll<Self::Output> {
        // non-blocking Device::poll call here
    }
}

Then you can construct a DeviceReady and await on that.
But unfortunately wgpu::Maintain does not offer a non-blocking variant that specifies a submission index, so this might not work for you. In such cases where the only API is a blocking one, the compromise I would go with is to use spawn_blocking (assuming you are using tokio) to create a Future that completes on thread termination:
tokio::task::spawn_blocking(move || device.poll(wgpu::Maintain::WaitForSubmissionIndex(idx))).await;

Note that you probably need to wrap device in an Arc because you are crossing thread boundaries. Also, this spawns an OS thread, which is considered relatively expensive compared to an async task (sometimes known as a "green thread"). So you would want to avoid doing this repeatedly in a hot path.
